# What can a RAM failure provoke on a cluster of computation units

Tags: memory, hardware

I am interested in some technical clues on how a failure on a RAM that is shared between multiple computation units (this could be virtual machines managed by hypervisor or two (or more) OSes running on two (or more) physically different computation units, that share the same RAM) can affect the behavior of the functions that run on these different computation units.

More precisely, what are the possible errors that can be provoked by a RAM failure when the RAM is shared between multiple systems? Can this failure be undected?

Comment: do you have a smp setup? I think that can be detected through that. Maybe look into scalemp? We need more information on how the cluster is setup.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: anything.

Whether the memory is shared or not, memory corruption trashes your data (or even the code) and renders the result completely useless. When the code is hit the application is likely to go haywire and might even trash more data. At the very least it'll crash more or less gracefully.

To avoid this, you might want to look into [ECC memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I am looking to find different kind of failures that could be provoked only by RAM failures, in order to abstract them in a model. TBH, I also think that this may be too broad to be clearly identified.

Comment: What kind of failures? Today, not only simple Hamming code is used but also more sophisticated techniques including chipkill and memory RAID, dealing with the loss of a chip or an entire DIMM.

Comment: Well, that's my question actually. I don't know what kind of failures are common in a RAM. Bit flip? Wrong access?

Comment: Single bit flips, row or column faults (rare), addressing faults, single chip death, total DIMM failure - all addressed I think.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. Do you have any resources related to how these failures could appear (the conditions) and how are they identifiable?